# Can this Rust match expression be simplified?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have a struct with 6 fields of the same type. I want to be able to get mutable references to them from an enum.

For example given the following simplified definitions:

```
struct S {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    cs: [i32; 3],
    d: i32,
}

enum E {
    A,
    B,
    COrD(COrD)
}

enum COrD {
    C1,
    C2,
    C3,
    D,
}
```

I want to write a function like this:

```
fn get_refs_mut<'a, T>(s: &'a mut S, e1: E, e2: E) -> RefsMut<'a, i32> {
    match (e1, e2) {
        (E::A, E::A) => RefsMut::Same(&mut S.a),
        (E::A, E::B) => RefsMut::Pair(&mut S.a, &mut S.b),
        (E::B, E::COrD(COrD::C1)) => RefsMut::Pair(&mut S.b, &mut S.c[0])
        // ...
        (E::B, E::A) => RefsMut::Pair(&mut S.b, &mut S.a),
        (E::B, E::B) => RefsMut::Same(&mut S.b),
        (E::B, E::COrD(COrD::C1)) => RefsMut::Pair(&mut S.b, &mut S.c[0]),
        // ...
        (E::COrD(COrD::D), E::COrD(COrD::D)) => RefsMut::Same(&mut S.d),
    }
}

enum RefsMut<'a, T> {
    Pair(&'a mut T, &'a mut T),
    Same(&'a mut T),
}
```

But as far as I can tell that will require me to manually specify the results for all 6 * 6 = 36 possible values for `(e1, e2)`, which is laborious. Is there any way to write this function in a terser manner?

Aside: The particular way I've defined `S` and `E` might seem odd. I have reasons for having the equivalent of `COrD` in the actual code, so I can refer those particular fields and related fields separately. Similarly, the real versions of the `cs` are also referred to together as well, hence they are in the array.

Comment: Your code is unreadable. `S` or `E` or all you one character variable is not a way to name thing. Use word not character. You even do a mistake yourself `h2: E` please rework that, do a better [mcve].

Comment: @Stargateur The actual domain i'm modelling is irrelevant to my question, so I thought that I would remove as many unneeded details as possible. This apparently backfired. Would it have been easier to read if I had named `S` and `E` `ExampleStruct` and `ExampleEnum`?.  Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @trentcl Hopefully now that I've actually filled out the beginning of the expression it's clear what the rest of it would be.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I really wasn't being deliberately obtuse; I just didn't realize the names of the enum variants were supposed to correlate to the names of the struct members. I figured they were all just arbitrary letters -- which is probably part of the reason the other commenters suggested making them more meaningful. It's always a fine balance between "minimal" and "complete". :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First write a function that gets a reference to a single member. Then call that function twice:

```
fn get_ref_mut<'a>(s: &'a mut S, e: E) -> &'a mut i32 {
    match e {
        E::A => &mut s.a,
        E::B => &mut s.b,
        E::COrD(c) => match c {
            COrD::C1 => &mut s.cs[0],
            COrD::C2 => &mut s.cs[1],
            COrD::C3 => &mut s.cs[2],
            COrD::D => &mut s.d,
        }
    }
}

fn get_refs_mut<'a>(s: &'a mut S, e1: E, e2: E) -> RefsMut<'a, i32> {
    if e1 == e2 {
        RefsMut::Same(get_ref_mut(s, e1))
    } else {
        let first: &mut i32 = unsafe {
            &mut *(get_ref_mut(s, e1) as *mut i32)
        };

        let second = get_ref_mut(s, e2);
        RefsMut::Pair(first, second)
    }
}
```

The `unsafe` block is necessary because we need to convert one of the references to a pointer and then dereference it in order to trick the borrow checker into thinking `first` does not reference `s`. That way it will let us borrow it a second time in `second`. But our code is still safe because we've structured it in a way that we are guaranteed to be referencing 2 different parts of `s`. This is similar to what [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) does, as explained in [The Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html).

Note that the expresstion `e1 == e2` will require you to implement (or derive) `PartialEq` for `E` and `COrD`. If for some reason you can't do that, you could compare `first` and `second` as pointers to see if they refer to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out what I meant, since I apparently did not make it easy. And thanks as well for actually providing an answer. I was hoping for a way that didn't use unsafe, but as you point out it is necessary.